# Map on array and save item to other array in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I have a array of arrays:

```
[["email", "test@test.com"], ["phone", 123123123], ["address", "street"]]
```

I want to create array where I will have only first element from every array:

```
["email", "phone", "address"]
```

I have something like that:

```
bigArray.map((field) => {
        this.smallArray.add(field[0]);
      });
```

but I got error: `Error in event handler for "bigArray": "TypeError: _this.smallArray.add is not a function"`

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = [["email", "test@test.com"], ["phone", 123123123], ["address", "street"], ["sameple"]]
const result = arr
  .filter(a => !!a[1])
  .map(a => a[0])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: one more thing: How can I add condition that this value should be added only when item[1] is empty?

Comment: Updated answer.. First you should filter

Comment: Perfect, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```js
this.smallArray = this.bigArray.map(arr => arr[0])
```

Comment: one more thing: How can I add condition that this value should be added only when item[1] is empty?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are tyring to add filtered element to `smallArray`. You should use.

```
this.smallArray.push(field[0]);
```